# navigate to new component in Reactjs onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck badly in an issue while making my app.

Suppose I have a single page app like this

home     about      contact us

Now if I click on any component then it will navigate to new component corresponding to the tab I clicked and I can achieve it through react router which i have already done

Now coming to my scenario

Here is the screenshot of my app

[image: doodles]

- Now I want when I click on **More About Doodles** then it should
  navigate to some other component and on clicking back button it comes
  back to home page.
  My App has a structure like this

  App class

  ```
  {

  render{

  return(

  <Header />
  <OccasionList />
  );
  }
  ```

  }

Now The page that is shown in screenshot has navigation bar as header component
and rest of the page is OccasionList component.

My problemis

- I want to navigate from OccasionList to some other js page or
  component that displays the description of the event on click event
  and only that component should be visible in the entire screen(something similr to single page apps)

I don't think react router will work in this case.

So how should i proceed now?

**UPDATE**
Why i think router won't fulfill this

say this is my entry point of app and routr redirects all my requests to App component

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={App}> 
<Route path="header" name="archives" component={Header}></Route>
<Route path="occasion" component={OccasionList}></Route>
</Route>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

Now it will redirect control to App component.Now my doubt is

**Usual approach**

```
class App extends React.Component {


   render() {


       return (   
         <div>
        {this.props.children}
         <Link to="header">header</Link>
         <Link to="occasons">occasons</Link>
           </div>
      );
   }
}
```

so on click to different components control will navigate to different pages.

But my doubt is
According to my App

```
class App extends React.Component {


   render() {


       return (   
         <div>

        {this.props.children}
         <Header>
         <OccasionList>

           </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Now **More About Doodles** according to image is present in occasionList component.So basically i need to do define link

More About Doodles

inside a child component rather that **App** component.

So main crux is

- Link basically helps in navigating to child components and  is defined in parent component
- In my case my parent component renders a child component which in turns will give a link that will navigate to a new component.

How will react router fulfill this functionality?

Comment: Why wouldn't react-router be valid for usage? It seems exactly what you want from the description you are giving

Comment: i have updated the question.Please help i am stuck since3-4 days